# Failed to unmount /home and /run/user/1000 on shutdown

Tags: mount, shutdown

When I shut down my 15.10 / kernel `4.2.0-22-generic` machine (without kernel parameter `quiet splash`, so that I see the messages on boot and shutdown), recently there are two red lines in those messages, like this:

```
[  Failed  ] Unmounting /home
[  Failed  ] Unmounting /run/user/1000
```

This is how I remember them, it might be not the exact wording...

The machine still powers off a few seconds later, but I wonder why these errors suddenly started to occur, whether they affect the safety of my data and how to fix them.

As a start, here's my `lsblk` output. If you need further information, don't hesitate to request it in a comment. Thanks!

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /win/boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    74G  0 part /win/c
├─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part /boot
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  31,3G  0 part /images
├─sda6   8:6    0    40G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0    60G  0 part /home
├─sda8   8:8    0    15G  0 part /win/share
└─sda9   8:9    0   4,6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0    19G  1 loop /old
```

Comment: Can you please include the excerpt of `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log` just before the last system shutdown? It hopefully contains more hints. Also, volume (un-)mounting should be handled by systemd, which should generate task-specific log files somewhere.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I could not find anything related to (un)mounting or shutting down in those logs, especially nothing that looked like a warning or an error.

Comment: You can also look into more [debugging output from the init system](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Debugging).